# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I am totally new to programming. I have 8 years of work experience in Network data domain and have very less understanding of programming. When ever i try to run my first GUI based python program I always get error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'". I did uninstall and reinstall of python many times but no luck. Till no i was using Python 3.6.2. Kindly suggest me how to resolve this and move further or which version should i use of python. Also, it will be very helpful if you explain me step by step to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you installed pyqt4?

Comment: Welcome to the programming world , have you consider installing a `pyqt4` pakage , through `pip` or from googling :"install pyqt4"

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to install them on the internet.

Comment: I would definitely recommend `PyQt5` as it's the newer version.

Comment: Hi, I installed PyQt4 through google and seen many videos on you tube but so far no luck..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
apt-cache search pyqt
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

or else you can find all the pyqt and its related packages [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pyqt&submit=search) for downloading and installing.

Also refer [this](http://movingthelamppost.com/blog/html/2013/07/12/installing_pyqt____because_it_s_too_good_for_pip_or_easy_install_.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows system, run: `pip install python-qt5` to get `PyQt5`.

This is the best way to install if you are new because it puts every file and things in the right place. I would consider using `PyQt5` as it is able to be installed with `pip`. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.